# Moving circle back and forth loop using if statements

Tags: javascript

For a school assignment I need to make a circle move back and forth in  p5.js webeditor.
I need to use if statements, variables and greater then, lesser then etc.
here is my script.

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  circle (200, y, 40);
  if (y >= 0){
    y++;
  }
  if (y >= 400){
    y--;
  }
}
```

I know that the problem is that when the second if statement is true, the first is also still true.

Comment: You need a specific "direction" (`dir = 1`) variable. Only change the value of `dir` when a limit is crossed, if the lower limit, change `dir` to 1, if the upper limit, change `dir` to -1. Then do `y += dir`.

Comment: Then what should the conditions of the if statements be. The circle does move down it just doesn't move up again because the if statements are conflicting.

Comment: The lower limit should be checked like `y <=  0`; And the "increment" of `y` should be done on every time, don't close it behind the passed conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it simply reverses the direction when the circle hits the top or bottom.

```
var y = 1;
var direction = true;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  circle (200, y, 40);
  if (direction){
    y++;
  } else {
   y--; 
  }

  if (y >= height || y <= 0){
    direction = !direction;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you maybe explain how the second if statement works step by step. I'm a beginner at coding so most of it looks like moon runes to me.

Comment: Yeah of course! The second if statement only runs when y >= height (when y is bigger or the same as the height) or when y <= 0 (when y is smaller or the same as 0). So || in a if statement means or. With that it changes the direction of circle, because !direction actually means the opposite of direction. So if direction was true before it is false now, and vice versa. And then in the first if statement it then checks if it is on its way up or down. :)